# Cannot fetch "birthday" field from Facebook in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

Recently I have decided to integrate the "Log in with Facebook" feature on one of my projects. Everything seems to work fine except for one thing: no matter what I try, I can't get the user's birthday.

I've set the application's permissions on facebook to request "email" and "user_birthday", but even when I log in with Facebook on my project I get asked to allow access to my basic data, 'friends list' and email - somehow, I believe, FB confuses "user_birthday" with "read_friendslist". Can this be true or am I missing something?

I am using Facebook C# SDK by Outercurve Foundation with the help of DotNetOpenAuth extension(s) in an ASP.NET MVC 4 project.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Well what does the Facebook C# SDK documentation say?

Comment: It doesn't say much (it's still 'under construction'), but to my understanding, everything should work fine. My main issue seems to be that facebook grants my application the wrong permission...could this be an error on their side?

Comment: You may want to check in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer to ensure you're getting the data you think you should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj863128.aspx) tutorial. It turns out it really was some sort of facebook bug, but asking for permissions explicitly made it work. The Facebook Javascript SDK also worked fine for me (I tried to switch at first).